# Razorpay nodejs express integration problem

Tags: javascript, node.js, razorpay

I am trying to make a checkout page using nodejs, and express with Razorpay as payment gateway. Razorpay runs when you click the "Checkout" button which is in my shopping-cart.hbs file. checkout() function is called on clicking Checkout button. The function is written in checkout.js file. But when I run the app, and click the button, it shows file not found. I don't know where the problem is. I have also installed razorpay in my npm.

```js
var razorpay = require('razorpay');

function checkout(){

    var options = {
        "key": "rzp_test_2eJE3rP3gEWqze", // Enter the Key ID generated from the Dashboard
        "amount": 50*100, // Amount is in currency subunits. Default currency is INR. Hence, 50000 refers to 50000 paise
        "currency": "INR",
        "name": "Modi's Dairy",
        "description": "Test Transaction",
        "image": "/images/modiLogo3.png",
        //"order_id": "order_9A33XWu170gUtm", //This is a sample Order ID. Pass the `id` obtained in the response of Step 1
        "handler": function (response){
            savetoDB(response);
           
        },
        "prefill": {
            "name": "Gaurav Kumar",
            "email": "gaurav.kumar@example.com",
            "contact": "9999999999"
        },
        "notes": {
            "address": "Razorpay Corporate Office"
        },
        "theme": {
            "color": "#F37254"
        }
    };

    var rzp1 = new Razorpay(options);
    rzp1.open(); 
}

function savetoDB(response){
    console.log(response);
    var payRef = firebase.database().ref('payment');

    /*payRef.child('123456789').set({

    }); */

}
```

```html
{{#if products}}
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-md-offset-3 col-sm-offset-3">
        <ul class="list-group">
            {{#each products}}
            <li class="list-group-item">
                <span class="badge">
                    {{this.qty}}
                </span>
                <strong>{{this.item.title}}</strong>
                <span class="label label-success">{{this.price}}</span>
                <div class="btn-group">
                    <button class="btn btn-primary btn-xs dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">Action </button>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li><a href="#">Reduce by 1</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Remove all</a></li> 
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </li>
            {{/each}}
            
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-md-offset-3 col-sm-offset-3">
        <strong>Total: {{totalPrice}}</strong>
    </div>
</div>
<hr>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-md-offset-3 col-sm-offset-3">
        <a  type="button" id="paymentClick" onclick ="checkout()" class="btn btn-success">Checkout</a>
    </div>
</div>
{{else}}
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-md-offset-3 col-sm-offset-3">
        <h2>No items in cart</h2>
    </div>
</div>
{{/if}}

<script src="/__/firebase/7.17.1/firebase-app.js"></script>

 <!-- Add Firebase products that you want to use -->
  <script src="/__/firebase/7.17.1/firebase-auth.js"></script>
  <script src="/__/firebase/7.17.1/firebase-database.js"></script>
  <script src="/__/firebase/init.js"></script>
  <script src="https://checkout.razorpay.com/v1/checkout.js"></script>
  <script src = "/javascripts/checkout.js"></script>
<script>
   
</script>
```

[Error msg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GJacG.png)

Answer (score 1):

You need to execute the checkout function on the front end and for that, you need to load https://checkout.razorpay.com/v1/checkout.js script. Checkout this document : [doc](https://razorpay.com/docs/payment-gateway/web-integration/standard)